# Security team making the firewall opening, good pratice?

Tags: network, firewalls, network-access-control

I'm currently requested in my enterprise to do myself (security team) the firewall overtures requests in TUFIN (firewall workflow), instead of our local IT team. it's for simplicity and saving costs.

These opening are at the end done by the network team of our IT provider with the control of the security team of the IT provider.

In terms of good pratice, do you think it could matter ?

In a first view :

- I'm controling what i'm doing (self judge), bad pratice.
- I'm are losing the 4 eyes principle control. Even if the IT provider could be considered as a kind of second eyes, it's sound not to be the same thing.

What's your opinion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it comes down to which trade-offs you are willing to make. We can give you the best practice approach here, but to deviate from the recommendation can be OK, given the circumstances.

The security team usually wants to be the second or third line of defense, **defining and overseeing the security practices** in the organisation. This means for your scenario, that you should **define and document**, how firewall configuration takes place and what the approval process for new rules look like. You also want to **audit the implementation of your defined procedure**. For highly critical rule changes - what this means for your organisation has to be defined by you as well - it makes sense to have a representative of the security team in the decision board.

And to answer your question - **separation of duties is crucial** here. You cannot oversee yourself, especially when it comes to security. So it is **not** recommended to have the security team perform first line of defense activities.